# No such file or directory, Weird Or What?

Tags: python, download, urllib2

So,

I've been coding a Downloader, and every time I run it, it says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Downloader.py", line 7, in <module>
    f = open('c:\\users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\mods\CreeperCraft.zip', 'wb+')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\users\\%USERNAME%\\AppData\\Roaming\\.minecraft\\mods\\CreeperCraft.zip'
```

I now, your probably going to say, create a file, but I want the  script to create the file.

So, can someone tell me what to fix? This is the code:

```
import urllib2
import os
import shutil
url = "https://dl.dropbox.com/u/29251693/CreeperCraft.zip"
file_name = url.split('/')[-1]
u = urllib2.urlopen(url)
f = open('c:\\users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\mods\CreeperCraft.zip', 'wb+')
meta = u.info()
file_size = int(meta.getheaders("Content-Length")[0])
print "Downloading: %s Bytes: %s" % (file_name, file_size)
file_size_dl = 0
block_sz = 8192
while True:
    buffer = u.read(block_sz)
    if not buffer:
        break
    file_size_dl += len(buffer)
    f.write(buffer)
    status = r"%10d  [%3.2f%%]" % (file_size_dl, file_size_dl * 100. / file_size)
    status = status + chr(8)*(len(status)+1)
    print status,
f.close()
```

Comment: Make sure that the directory is there and if not, use [makedirs](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.makedirs) to make it.

Comment: Does Python's `open` function really expand environment variables on windows? (`c:\\users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\mods\CreeperCraft.zip`)

Comment: You may be better off using `%APPDATA` rather than `C:\Users\%USERNAME\AppData\Roaming`. Also, use raw strings (`r'c:\...'`) or forward slashes to avoid having to double backslashes in paths.

Answer (score 10):

The problem is that python doesn't realize that you're using %USERNAME% to refer to an environment variable, so python interprets it literally. You have to tell python that it's an environment variable, by doing this:

Replace

```
f = open('c:\\users\\%USERNAME%\\AppData\\Roaming\\.minecraft\\mods\\CreeperCraft.zip', 'wb+')
```

with

```
import os
f = open(os.path.expandvars('c:\\users\\%USERNAME%\\AppData\\Roaming\\.minecraft\\mods\\CreeperCraft.zip'), 'wb+')
```

Comment: Also, use [os.path.join](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to join the paths.

Comment: Thanks for the expandvars tip.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that `%USERNAME%` is not expanded by default.  Use [`os.path.expandvars`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.expandvars) on your path.

```
fp = path.expandvars(r'c:\\users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\mods\CreeperCraft.zip')
```

Answer (score 0):

My method was to make the AppData folder "un-hidden" in Windows Explorer, then just access it normally through Python as you would with other files, i.e Python can't see AppData on the cmd line until you "unhide" it, then you can access it as a normal directory.